# How could I install as service a gRPC service that is in in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 project that hosts a gRPC service. But I would like to install this project as a Windows service.

This is my code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

using GestorOrdenadores.Service.Server.Grpc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
{
    string miStrCertificado = File.ReadAllText("certificados/server.crt");
    string miStrKey = File.ReadAllText("certificados/server.key");
    X509Certificate2 miCertficadoX509 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(miStrCertificado, miStrKey);

    X509Certificate2 miCertificado2 = new X509Certificate2(miCertficadoX509.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));

    miCertficadoX509.Dispose();

    options.ListenAnyIP(5000);
    options.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
        listenOptions.UseHttps(miCertificado2);
    });
});

builder.Services.AddGrpc();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGrpcService<GestorOrdenadoresService>();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");

app.Run();
```

But when I try to added as service, the service is created, but I can't start it. So I guess I have to configure something to do it.

If I am not wrong, .NET 6 has the new `WebApplicationBuilder` that can be used for that, but I am not sure.

How could I create a Windows service with my ASP.NET Core project that host a gRPC service?

Thanks.

Comment: Why won't it start? Did you check the event log on windows for the startup error?

Comment: Just as a note, starting ASP.NET core as a service is done exactly the same way regardless whether your application uses gRPC or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems really.

First, I have to set the code that allow to install as service. This is the code:

```
WebApplicationOptions options = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
};
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
```

The second problem it is to set the correct application folder, write this code as first line of code in the program.cs file:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

The problem is that I was using logging and the logging is saved in a subfolder of the application folder. By default, the application folder is widnows\system32, that is the default folder of the services. So I have to set another folder in which I have write permissions. But it seems it will be solved in .NET 7.

The complete code of my program.cs file is this:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

using GestorOrdenadores.Service.Server.Grpc;
using Serilog;


Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);




Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateBootstrapLogger();

Log.Information("Starting up");






try
{
    WebApplicationOptions options = new WebApplicationOptions
    {
        Args = args,
        ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
    };
    WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);







    //Para el log
    builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
           .WriteTo.Console()
           .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));




    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
    {
        string miStrCertificado = File.ReadAllText("certificados/server.crt");
        string miStrKey = File.ReadAllText("certificados/server.key");
        X509Certificate2 miCertficadoX509 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(miStrCertificado, miStrKey);

        //Se necesita crear un segundo certficado a partir del primero porque si no, se obtiene un error.
        //Se tiene información en las siguientes incidencias:
        //https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/74093
        X509Certificate2 miCertificado2 = new X509Certificate2(miCertficadoX509.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));

        miCertficadoX509.Dispose();


        options.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
            listenOptions.UseHttps(miCertificado2);
        });
    });




    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddGrpc(opciones =>
    {
        opciones.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });
 
    builder.Host.UseWindowsService();





    WebApplication app = builder.Build();


    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();


    app.MapGrpcService<GestorOrdenadoresService>();




    app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");





    await app.RunAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Unhandled exception");
}
finally
{
    Log.Information("Shut down complete");
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Thanks for the help.